# Smart table reset / refresh on input field search does not load the original data

Tags: angularjs, reload, smart-table

When refreshing the table data with search input field, it displays table data with the last search input field value.

How can I remove the filter on the click of the refresh/clear button and get the original data?

Please find the page view [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cai2.png)

```js
 $scope.Refresh = function () {
        $scope.searchall="";     
        $scope.DataLoad();      
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="Refresh()">Refresh</button>
<div>
   <select autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px;" ng-model="CountPerPage"
   ng- options="x for x in CountPerPageOptionValues">
   <option value="">All</option>
   </select>
</div>
<table ng-show="DataLoaded" st-table="Collection" class="table table-striped animate-show" st-safe-src="data" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="Id">ID</th>
            <th st-sort="Name">Name</th>
            <th st-sort="Timestamp" style="min-width:68px;">Timestamp</th>
            <th st-sort="Message" style="min-width:136px;">Message</th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <th>
                <input ng-model="searchall" ng-show="!nomsg" st-search="Name" placeholder="search for Name" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:140px" type="search" />
             </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody data-ng-hide="isLoading" data-ng-animate="'fade'">
                                        *emphasized text*<tr ng-repeat="latestData in Collection">
                                            <td>{{latestData .Id}}</td>
                                            <td>{{latestData .Name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{latestData .Timestamp | date:'dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{latestData.Message}}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                                                <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="CountPerPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
```

Comment: can you create a codePen or an stack snippet where your code actually works?

Comment: @Re9iNee I have attached the GUI in question please view that. 1. if I search with text test in the input field I will get the required result. 2. now I click on the clear button and the test input is removed from the field but getting the data searched for the test. I want when on click of clear button the test filter will be removed along with the original data should get displayed not test data.

Comment: on clear button call the DataLoad function is getting the original data but I don't know why in view it is showing old searched data.

Comment: https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/164 has solved my issue.